# knockout js template passing json data source to template

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, x-editable

I am new to Knockout and its templating feature, I have the following html, can somebody help me framing a suitable template to replace its string literals and data source, I am using x-editable,#

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: fundClasses">
    <td class="span1">
        <span data-bind="visible: $index() == 0">  Rate Index</span>
    </td>
    <td class="span1 protected">
        <span data-bind=" editable:INDEX_ID,  editableOptions: {name:'INDEX_ID',mode: 'popup',type: 'select', source: rateIndex,pk: ID, url: '/create/EditInPlace'}"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to replace rateIndex, INDEX_ID in the snippets above, any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks 
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, so thought of answering so that would help others looking for similar issues,

Template:

```
<script id="textBoxTemplate" type=“text/html”>
   <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
    <td class="span1">
        <span data-bind="visible: $index() == 0,text:title">  </span>
    </td>
    <td class="span1 protected">
         <span data-bind="editable:$data[field],editableOptions: {  mode: 'popup', pk: ID, url: '/create/EditInPlace'}"></span>
   </td>
   <!-- /ko -->
```

Usage:

```
<tr data-bind="templateWithContext: { name: 'textBoxTemplate', data: fundClasses, context: { title: 'Index', field:'INDEX_ID' }}"></tr>
```

Binding Handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.templateWithContext = {
    init: ko.bindingHandlers.template.init,
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        ko.utils.extend(context, options.context);

        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.update.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```